# May I use video.js as a minimalistic polyfill?

Tags: video.js

I'd like to have a library that would offer a javascript API to control a player and manage its events, nothing more.

All the GUI would (optionnaly) not be part of the library. I've tried to set a player without controls, but even in that case the GUI is created in the DOM but not shown.

I can see 2 benefits: i can reuse my previous GUI in an easier way, and the video.js script is smaller.

But this also question the nature of the polyfill. Adding a track to manage subtitles without an interface to render it would not make a true polyfill. There would be 2 kinds of polyfill: the first would just let the browser play the video, and the second would create a consistent graphical interface to manage all the player's features.

The answerable question is: does video.js offers a way to only provide a js API (and modify the dom when flash is required)?

If there is not such feature, is it an option for the future (and why not)?

Thank you all!

Comment: In the latest version (4.10) you can set the option `{ "controlBar": false }` and it shouldn't build the html of the controls.

Comment: Is the main issue that you want to use your previously built controls instead of the video.js controls?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I had to switch on another project. I was hopping videojs would provide two interfaces: one for the developer, one for the user. The later would be optional. The first would update the dom only if a plugin is required to play the video. I've just tried the `{ "controlBar": false }` and it's fine for now. Hope my question got clearer, and thanks for your patience!